# Eliding async and await on HttpClient is not throwing exception on OSX

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio, async-await

After reading Stephen Cleary blog post about [eliding async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) I've decided to go and play around with it. I wrote very simple console app with HttpClient using **Visual Studio For Mac**.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(await Get());
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}

public static Task<string> Get()
{
    using (var http = new HttpClient())
        return http.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
}
```

According to blog post it should throw an exception **but it didn't**. If I switch to Windows and try to run this app, I will get TaskCancelledException as expected, but on macOS it works perfectly fine.

[Proof that Google.com was printed into console without exception on macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC433.jpg)

As I believe the reason behind this behaviour is different implementation of IDisposable in HttpClient on both platforms, but... why?

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? Is it .net core?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.1 with latest C#. HttpClient version 2.2.29. Execution file (.exe) built on macOS is failing on Windows but not on macOS.

Comment: @DominikPrzywara are you sure its .NET 4.7.1?  As far as I know you can only build .NET Core on a Mac

Comment: @maccettura yes, you can according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites and what I see in my project :D (created using macOS :P)

Comment: @DominikPrzywara I mispoke.  I meant as far as I know you can _only_ build .NET Core on a Mac

Comment: @maccettura According to <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion> this line in my .csproj (as I mentioned - created using Visual Studio For Mac).

Comment: I suspect it's just a different implementation of the underpinnings of `HttpClient`, which doesn't cancel tasks when the client is disposed.

Comment: I'd suggest to check state of `GetStringAsync` task before leaving using block. So `var task = http.GetStringAsync("http://google.com"); Console.WriteLine(task.Status)`. Maybe for some reason it returns already completed.

Comment: @Evk I've checked it already - WaitingForActivation before I hit await and it's like 1sec to get response from google.com, so there is no chance to get precomputed value before Dispose method should hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing [mono repository](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs#L113) with [dotnet repository](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L601) I've found, that mono implementation of HttpClient do not call CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() in Dispose method and I believe that's the reason of inconsistency between platforms.